# kusto database as string - issues in query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I m getting database name from let statement (dbname) , the issue im getting blank output ,but when I pass the db name [when I give as hardcoded value, the query is working] . please help me to understand what the issue in query.

```
let view=datatable(Property:string,Value:dynamic)[];
let viewFile=datatable(FileName:string)[];
let dbnameview=datatable(dbname:string)[];
alias database db = cluster(X).database('');
let dbname=tostring(toscalar((
    union isfuzzy=true dbnameview, cluster(X).database('$systemdb').Operations 
    | where Operation == "DatabaseCreate" and Database contains "oci-"| where State =='Completed' 
    and  StartedOn between (datetime(2020-04-09) .. 1d)
    | distinct Database , StartedOn 
    | order by StartedOn desc 
    | take 1 )));
//let dbname= 'Y';
 let latestInfoFile = toscalar((
    union isfuzzy=true viewFile,cluster(X).database(dbname).['TextFileLogs'] 
    | where FileName contains "AzureStackStampInformation" 
    | distinct FileName 
    | order by FileName 
    | take 1)) ;   
union isfuzzy=true view,(
    cluster(X).database(dbname).['TextFileLogs']
    | where FileName == latestInfoFile
    | distinct LineNumber,FileLineContent
    | order by LineNumber asc
    | summarize StampInfo=(toobject(strcat_array(makelist(FileLineContent,100000), "\r\n")))
    | mvexpand bagexpansion=array StampInfo
    | project Property=tostring(StampInfo[0]), Value=StampInfo[1] 
)|where Property contains "StampVersion" | project BuildNumber = Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

what you're attempting to do isn't supported, as mentioned in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/databasefunction

[image: pasted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/databasefunction]

Comment: Thank you @yoni L

Comment: hi @vaishnavi please mark Yoni's reply as an "answer" so it will help other people know that it is validated. Thanks much!

Comment: Hi @Yoni,  is there any any other possible way to pass the db name from query to its subquery?

Comment: one option would be: generating the query text programmatically (by running your query, getting the database name, then 'planting' it in the final query text), then running the final query programmatically